# probability that pie contains no apple slice

Tags: probability

A cook makes $3$ apple pies. Suppose he has $n$ apple slices which he puts into the mixture before dividing the mixture into $3$ apple pie pans. Find the probability that at least an apple pie contains no apple slice.

Comment: Found, now what?

Comment: Sorry, if I sounded like I obliged anyone to work it out for me. I found a similar question in an a internet paper (meaning it's not a homework or anything), but I couldn't solve it. If anyone could show some steps towards a proof, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well you know that atleast 1 apple pie has to have apple slices.

Therefore, either 2 Apple pies can have no apple slices or 1 Apple pie can have no apple slices.

There's a hint.